# SSH in with alternative shell

Tags: ssh, shell, login

We have a shared account on our system, which has login shell tcsh.  I prefer bash and would like to have it run bash when I ssh in from my personal account but leave tcsh for anyone else using the account.  I know I could set something up reflecting on the IP I ssh in from, but is there any (kludgy or non-kludgy) way to do this based on the user who ran ssh?  Or a way to run ssh to get it to give me an interactive bash session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, that wasn't hard to Google once I realized what I wanted: ssh -t user@host bash